# Increase each node's value in a binary tree by 1

Tags: java

So the exercise I am trying to do is:

Write a recursive function to increment by one the value for every node in the binary tree pointed at by "root" then return the modified tree. Assume that nodes store integer values. (-1 means a NULL pointer)

The code I have so far is:

```
public BinNode BTinc(BinNode root)
{

    if (root.right == null && root.left == null){
        root.setValue(root.value() + 1);
        return root;
    }

    if (root.left != null) {
        root.left.setValue(root.left.value() + 1);
        return BTinc(root.left);
    }

    if (root.right != null) { 
        root.right.setValue(root.right.value() + 1);
        return BTinc(root.right);   
    } 


    return root;

}
```

The problem I am having so far occurs when the root being passed in is -1, in which I get a null pointer exception. I am a bit confused on how this is happening. Is it because I am trying to access the right and left pointers of the null pointer?

Comment: You're exactly right. Check if the root is null at the top and return it if it is

Comment: you're not checking if(root != null) {// do something}. that should be the first thing to perform check on.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much. This might sound like a stupid question but why can't I just check if the root's value is -1 and return it?

Comment: @UnitingDust see my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in which I get a null pointer exception. I am a bit confused on how
>   this is happening

you cannot just perform `root.setValue(root.value() + 1);` because what if the root is `null`?

you'll need to check if `root` is **not** equal to null prior to performing `root.setValue`.

```
if (root != null && root.right == null && root.left == null){ // if both left and right nodes are null then simply return root
    root.setValue(root.value() + 1); 
    return root;
}
```

it's then up to you to set the appropriate value for the root.

Comment: Got it! I was misinterpreting the question. I literally thought that the node had a value of -1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to check if the left or right node is null or not, it's inefficient. *"You do not look at the children to decide whether to make a recursive call."* Just access the root and add value and leave the recursive call to do the rest.

```
public BinNode BTinc(BinNode root){
    if (root != null) {
        root.setValue(root.value() + 1);
        BTinc (root.left());
        BTinc (root.right());
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: If first condition is false, second condition is redudant, and thus last returned value as well.

Comment: I removed redundant parts of the code, preserving the same behavior. Consider. If root == null, it will go to return root. If else, it will go to return root too.